# Casting pointer value expression

Tags: go

I'm trying to figure out what this expression does:

```
(*levelValue)(&level)
```

I don't understand what is happening, it seems like it dereferencing `levelValue` first, but not sure why as the type of `levelValue` is `int32`

Some context below

```
import "flag"

type Level int32
type levelValue Level

// LevelFlag defines a Level flag with specified name, default value and
// usage string. The return value is the address of a Level value that stores
// the value of the flag.
func LevelFlag(name string, defaultLevel Level, usage string) *Level {
    level := defaultLevel
    flag.Var((*levelValue)(&level), name, usage)
    return &level
}

func (l *levelValue) Set(s string) error {
    return (*Level)(l).UnmarshalText([]byte(s))
}

func (l *levelValue) String() string {
    return (*Level)(l).String()
}
```

[Reference](https://github.com/uber-go/zap/blob/ddb695130b9f539d11ae0eb35332039f54225622/flag.go)

Comment: FYI: Go is a statically typed language and does not support `casting`. What you are seeing above is a type *conversion* - which is allowed here since the one type derives from the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type conversion:

When you define a type like that

```
type A B
```

You can convert a variable of type B to type A like that:

```
b := B
a := A(b)
```

In your case, the type `A` is `(*levelValue)` (The parenthesis are needed to specify that the type is a pointer to a `levelValue`. And the variable `b` is `&level` (A pointer that points to the variable `level`)

Comment: thanks for the comment.
"And the variable b is &level (A pointer that points to the variable level)"

wouldn't b be the address of the variable level?

Comment: Yes one can say that it is the address of the variable

Comment: thanks, i think i was missing the idea of type conversion